# Best way of approach? Mob moving around a section of tiles

Tags: ai, tilemap, tiles

Think the beginning stages of Metroid, where there would be a turtle-like mob that would move around a section of tiles, normally 1-3 in a line.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this sort of AI?

It seems so simple but its giving me headache.

The solution I've found have been to have a fixed distance for it to move, and changing directions once the distance has been met. This isn't that OOP though.

Another would be have a rectangle made of the section of tiles, and when the bounds of the mob no longer contains the line of rectangle, change directions. This is proving to be harder to implement and only works for rectangular sections, not for abstract "tetris" like sections of tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy way of doing it, after having troubles with getting smooth movement under milk's suggestion. Here's the source, (python / jython):

s == the mob, and territory == its rectangular "home" area.
The +1's and +2's I added to some corners to make it look better as it was a bit "snappy".

```
fullBounds = s.getFullBounds()
rightBounds = s.getRightBounds()
leftBounds = s.getLeftBounds()
topBounds = s.getTopBounds()
bottomBounds = s.getBottomBounds()

top = s.territory.getTop()
right = s.territory.getRight()
left = s.territory.getLeft()
bottom = s.territory.getBottom()

if s.clockWise:
    if fullBounds.intersects(right) and not fullBounds.intersects(bottom):    
        s.setVelocity(0, speed)
        s.setX(s.territory.pos.x + s.territory.getWidth())
        s.setY(restrict(s.getY(), s.territory.getY() - 2))
    elif fullBounds.intersects(top): 
        s.setVelocity(speed, 0)
        s.setY(s.territory.pos.y - s.HEIGHT)
        s.setX(restrict(s.getX(), s.territory.getX() - 1))


    if fullBounds.intersects(left) and not fullBounds.intersects(top) and not topBounds.intersects(bottom):     
        s.setVelocity(0, -speed)
        s.setX(s.territory.pos.x - s.HEIGHT)
    elif fullBounds.intersects(bottom):   
        s.setVelocity(-speed, 0)
        s.setY(s.territory.pos.y + 2 + s.HEIGHT)


elif not s.clockWise:
    if fullBounds.intersects(right) and not fullBounds.intersects(top):    
        s.setVelocity(0, -speed)
        s.setX(s.territory.pos.x + s.territory.getWidth())
        s.setY(restrict(s.getY(), s.territory.getY() - 2))
    elif fullBounds.intersects(top) and not fullBounds.intersects(left): 
        s.setVelocity(-speed, 0)
        s.setY(s.territory.pos.y - s.HEIGHT)


    if fullBounds.intersects(bottom) and not fullBounds.intersects(right):     
        s.setVelocity(speed, 0)
        s.setY(s.territory.pos.y + s.HEIGHT + 2)
    elif fullBounds.intersects(left):   
        s.setVelocity(0, speed)
        s.setX(s.territory.pos.x - s.HEIGHT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to patrol between different locations, so you could just create a list of locations to visit in order (so you would have two locations for a move back and forth behavior). Once your actor has visited each location she can start over and return to the first location (or you could visit the locations in reverse order, or stop, or whatever).

For arbitrary shaped patrols like you mention in the last paragraph, you can just add more locations to visit on the patrol (eg- (0,0) -> (5,0) -> (5,5) to create an L-shaped patrol).

Some pseudo-code for this kind of behavior:

```
class Patroller
{
    private List<Location> _locationsToVisit;

    private int _nextLocationIndex;

    public void Update()
    {
        // Visit each location
        var nextLocation = _locationsToVisit[_nextLocationIndex];
        MoveToward(nextLocation);

        if (IsAt(nextLocation))
        {
            _nextLocationIndex++;
            // If visited each location, then set the next as the first location.
            // Alternately you could start visiting the locations in reverse order
            if (_nextLocationIndex >= _locationsToVisit.Count)
            {
                _nextLocationIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks much easier than worrying about intersection of lines and rectangles hahaaha